# How to update DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in tmux when that address changes?

Tags: terminal, tmux, dbus

I have noticed, that I can’t run steam in a tmux pane: it gave me error

```
Error: Unable to open a connection to X.  Check your DISPLAY environment
variable and make sure that you have enabled X.  If you are running
remotely, make sure that you have a remote connection which will allow
an X connection.
```

When at the same time there’s no such problem in a usual terminal. That guided me to a conclusion that something differs in the program environment, an I was right, after exporting the environment from both terminals

```
$ env > /tmp/t1
$ env > /tmp/t2
```

And diffing them

```
$ diff -u /tmp/t{1,2}
```

I’ve noticed that DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS differs

```
-DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-CX81GDMBcL,guid=712e96f4ecdc3b9bf1eca21254ed44e3
+DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-axu0HojvNi,guid=a28fcde62f6d40aa587c708a54b83924
```

It must be because I may restart X and the environment in `tmux` sessions doesn’t get affected by the `dbus-launch` which takes place in my WM starting command in ~/.xinitrc:

```
eval exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session i3 &>/dev/null
```

So, how do I update that variable when the address changes?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/me dumb. I just needed to reexport DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in my tmux windows in the autostart script when I check whether it’s already running or should it start.

So the section related to tmux in my autorun.sh now looks like that:

```
tmux="tmux -u -f $HOME/.tmux/config -S $HOME/.tmux/socket"
if pgrep -u $UID -f '^tmux.*$' &>/dev/null; then
    for pane in `$tmux list-windows -t0 | sed -r 's/^([0-9]+):.*/\1/g'`; do
        $tmux send -t 0:$pane C-c 
        $tmux send -t 0:$pane export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ENTER
        $tmux send -t 0:$pane export DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" ENTER
        $tmux send -t 0:$pane C-c
    done
else $tmux \
    new -d su \; \
    set remain-on-exit on \; \
    neww su \; \
    set remain-on-exit on \; \
    select-window -t 0:1
fi
```

---

The first `C-c` is to clear the line from anything that might left there before running export commands. The second is to clear the line afterwards (tmux or bash will copy the commands to the command line, I don’t know why)

Comment: No, I was wrong. This doesn’t help. Or it is not sufficient.

Comment: Of course not, I forgot to export `DISPLAY`, too! Now it works fine.